# Why does the Node crypto library do Diffie Hellman this way?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, diffie-hellman

I was sifting through the Node Crytpo library and I came across their Diffie Hellman utility [class](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_diffiehellman). Their class implements a `generateKeys` function that, in their words,

> Generates private and public Diffie-Hellman key values, and returns
>   the public key in the specified encoding

My understanding of **Diffie Hellman** is that both parties only ever need to generate a single random number, not a public/private key. I suppose that you could call this random number a public key and that's what this function returns, but where does a private key come into this process?

I know that in **Station to Station** protocol a public/private key pair is used for signing. Is that what is happening here? Could this class be used for Station to Station protocol as is?

Comment: DH uses two keypairs, one for each party, each consisting of a private key and a public key, to _derive_ a share secret. Generating a keypair consists of choosing the private key randomly (and secretly) and _computing_ the public key, so yes each party only chooses one random (per instance) but they do more than just choose that one random. For STS each party needs a DH keypair _and_ a signing keypair; that class could provide the former (only) and do part but not all of the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding of Diffie Hellman is that both parties only ever need to generate a single random number, not a public/private key.

That is not correct.

[Wikipedia’s entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation) covers it pretty well. Once two parties have agreed upon a domain (the (g, p) pair) each member generates their own private key. Their shared secret is equal to

```
(g ^ (a * b)) % p
```

where `a` is Alice’s private key and `b` is Bob’s. Of course, each side can do this calculation without the other party revealing their private key.